# Another OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget (due to transparency) - Android

Tags: android, image, transparency

I've searched on this thoroughly for a few days and haven't come up with much.  Every other instance I have read deals with garbage collection.

What I'm doing is loading a 4 KB PNG image which is basically completely transparent with small white "stars".  It is 1000x750.  Just loading this one image when the program starts gives an OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget and  E/dalvikvm-heap(3941): 27000000-byte external allocation too large for this process.

With the exact same code I have no problem loading a 176KB PNG background image with no transparency.  It's just a simple "stars1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.back3c);"

So is there some correlation where decoding a transparent PNG takes up an insane amount of memory?  And is there any way to fix this other than using a smaller image?

If I scale the image down to 500x375 it loads fine.  I guess I'm just wondering if there is a better way to deal with a transparent image if that is the issue.

The code is almost directly the LunarLander example.  Code actually decoding the bitmap:

```
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inTempStorage = new byte[16*1024];
        options.inSampleSize = 12;

        stars1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.back4e);

        //stars1 = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back3c);
        //stars2 = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back4b);
        BackgroundImage = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back2);
```

Comment: @can you put part of your code?

Comment: mostly these out of memory error occurs because of emulator .. try running app in device and check

Comment: I'm running it to my atrix from eclipse.